# Getting channelId instead of teamId from the context

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, chatbot

I am developing an Extension in Microsoft Teams.

I am interested in knowing from **where the extension was invoked meaning from which team?**

Below is the code base and steps I did and found an issue (or bug).

```
async handleTeamsMessagingExtensionFetchTask(context, action) {
    console.log(context._activity.channelData);
}
```

```
{
  channel: { id: '19:123456789@thread.tacv2' },
  team: { id: '19:123456789@thread.tacv2' },
  tenant: { id: '5xxx-xxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxx' },
  source: { name: 'compose' }
}
```

So, above you can see the channel data I am getting contains the channel and team id - over here I am entering the random numbers - but the main point is in the team id I get the same value as channel id

**See the image below for more clarity:**

[image]

**My question, is that a bug? or this what it is intended to do?**

Answer (score 1):

I think you're seeing the "General" Channel - it's basically the "default" in every Team, and every Team will definitely have a "General" Channel, so it's given the same ID. You can check by looking at alternate channels in the same Team, of course.

Comment: Yeah I opened the extension in the `general channel`  of the team but it should return a different id under `teamed` not the same as `channelId`

Comment: like I said, I think it will send the same value for both if you're in General. Were you able to test another channel to confirm?

Comment: Yeah, I am getting the channel id different but the teamId = general channel id. But that’s confusing!!  So, do you know how I can get the actual id of the team where the extension is invoked?

Comment: As mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/get-teams-context?tabs=dotnet#get-the-list-of-channels-in-a-team), The channel ID for the General channel always matches the team ID.

Comment: oh, I see now, you're worried about not getting the Team Id - I think it's the opposite - you ARE getting the Team Id, it's just being shared with the channel because it's General channel. @Prasad-MSFT's answer covers that